# How to fix the error of **form_with** tag not submitting an associative model attributes to params in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 3 models of **User**, **UserActivity**, and **Activity**. I have created  an association between them and when I submit values through its form, I can see the values at the back of the console but I get validation errors of empty fields.

I have tried several means including search different forums and trying out the different suggestion but to no avail.

## The Models

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :role #, foreign_key: "id"

    has_many :user_activities, inverse_of: :user
    has_many :activities, through: :user_activities

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_activities
end

class UserActivity < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :user_activities
    belongs_to :activity, inverse_of: :user_activities, optional: true

    attr_accessor :user_activity_date, :user_activity_start,  :user_activity_end, :user_activity_note, :activity_id, :user_id

    validates_presence_of :user_activity_end, presence: true, null: false, :message => "cannot be empty"
    validates_presence_of :user_activity_start, presence: true, null: false, :message => "cannot be empty"
    validates_presence_of :user_activity_date, presence: true, null: false, :message => "cannot be empty"
    validates_presence_of :user_activity_note, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }, null: false, :message => "cannot be empty"

end

class Activity < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :user_activities, inverse_of: :activity
  has_many :users, through: :user_activities

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_activities

end
```

## The Controller Methods

```
class UserActivitiesController < ApplicationController

   # GET /user_activities/new
   def new
        @user_activity = current_user.user_activities.build(activity_id: params[:activity_id])

        @activity = Activity.all
    end
  end

     # POST /user_activities
     # POST /user_activities.json
     def create
        @user_activity = current_user.user_activities.build
        respond_to do |format|
            if @user_activity.save
               format.html { redirect_to @user_activity, notice: 'User activity was successfully created.' }
               format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user_activity }
            else
                @activities = Activity.all
                format.html { render :new }
                format.json { render json: @user_activity.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
       end
    end

    def user_activity_params
        params.require(:user_activity).permit( :user_activity => [:activity_id, :user_activity_date, :user_activity_start, :user_activity_end, :user_activity_note])
    end
end
```

## The View

***I have removed some of the fields just to reduce the number line of codes***

```
<%= form_with(model: user_activity, local: true) do |frm| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= frm.label :activity_id %><br />
    <%= collection_select(:user_activity, :activity_id, Activity.all, :id, :activity_name, prompt: true) %>
    <%#= select("user_activity", "activity_id", Activity.all.collect {|a| [ a.activity_name, a.id ] }, {include_blank: 'none'}) %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= frm.label(get_user_activity_date) %><br />
    <%= frm.date_field :user_activity_date, autofocus: true%>
   </div>

<% end %>
```

## Results on the Console

```
Started POST "/user_activities" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-16 04:10:28 +0100
Processing by UserActivitiesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"o81mDoZ87/hodGpWaHkH/CDs87Hr2nH+s518GCp8q3GZC650UrRh0hYTCu41ax3vjUhgRC3JkP03ZHbVIYYQJQ==", "user_activity"=>{"activity_id"=>"", "user_activity_date"=>"", "user_activity_start"=>"", "user_activity_end"=>"", "user_activity_note"=>"a test message I place here""}, "commit"=>"Create User activity"}
```

I expected that the form data submitted will be passed to the **user_activity_params** in the controller but then it does not as it keeps returning an error message of all the fields in the form been blank.

### The Error Message in FireFox

```
4 errors prohibited this user_activity from being saved:
   User activity end cannot be empty
   User activity start cannot be empty
   User activity date cannot be empty
   User activity note cannot be empty
```

And because of this I cannot save the data into the **user_activities** table in the database.

## Update of the Server Log

```
Started POST "/user_activities" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-16 21:15:48 +0100
Processing by UserActivitiesController#create as HTML
    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"7v79xk6TW0IHNjkno+iXwzIYqqBjBMxCSodddPHUmKI/N4C9W6nkFz7qApXaQMEFJL6Qumn6BfsX/gxueMjp2w==", "user_activity"=>{"activity_id"=>"1", "user_activity_date"=>"2019-01-15", "user_activity_start"=>"20:14", "user_activity_end"=>"21:15", "user_activity_note"=>"testing to see if values can be retrieved"}, "commit"=>"Create User activity"}
    Activity ID -> 1
    Date -> 2019-01-15
    Start Time -> 20:14
    End Time -> 21:15
    Activity Note -> testing to see if values can be retrieved

        User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
        ↳ app/controllers/user_activities_controller.rb:46
    (0.5ms)  BEGIN
        ↳ app/controllers/user_activities_controller.rb:46
        UserActivity Create (3.0ms)  INSERT INTO `user_activities` (`created_at`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) VALUES ('2019-01-16 20:15:49', '2019-01-16 20:15:49', 1)
        ↳ app/controllers/user_activities_controller.rb:46
        (0.5ms)  ROLLBACK
        ↳ app/controllers/user_activities_controller.rb:46
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 125ms (ActiveRecord: 12.4ms)

ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (Mysql2::Error: Field 'user_activity_date' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `user_activities` (`created_at`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) VALUES ('2019-01-16 20:15:49', '2019-01-16 20:15:49', 1)):

app/controllers/user_activities_controller.rb:46:in `create'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed the errors I was receiving just after trying out most recommendations without solutions. 
I started by going through the model associations and disabling some methods such as inverse_of, accepts_nested_attribute_for, and attr_accessor, one after the other.

## Before

```
class UserActivity < ApplicationRecord

    # ----ASSOCIATION OF MODELS----

    # a UserActivity belongs to a User
    # and UserActivity belongs to an Activity
    belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :user_activities
    belongs_to :activity, optional: true, inverse_of: :user_activities 

    attr_accessor :user_activity_date, :user_activity_start,  :user_activity_end, :user_activity_note, :activity_id, :user_id

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :activity, :user

    # ----MODEL VALIDATIONS----
    validates_presence_of :user_activity_end, presence: true, null: false, :message => "cannot be empty"
    validates_presence_of :user_activity_start, presence: true, null: false, :message => "cannot be empty"
    validates_presence_of :user_activity_date, presence: true, null: false, :message => "cannot be empty"
    validates_presence_of :user_activity_note, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }, null: false, :message => "cannot be empty"

    validates :user, presence: true
    validates :activity, presence: true
end
```

## After

```
class UserActivity < ApplicationRecord

    # ----ASSOCIATION OF MODELS----

    # a UserActivity belongs to a User
    # and UserActivity belongs to an Activity
    belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :user_activities
    belongs_to :activity, optional: true, inverse_of: :user_activities 

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :activity, :user

    # ----MODEL VALIDATIONS----
    validates_presence_of :user_activity_end, presence: true, null: false, :message => "cannot be empty"
    validates_presence_of :user_activity_start, presence: true, null: false, :message => "cannot be empty"
    validates_presence_of :user_activity_date, presence: true, null: false, :message => "cannot be empty"
    validates_presence_of :user_activity_note, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }, null: false, :message => "cannot be empty"

    validates :user, presence: true
    validates :activity, presence: true
end
```

## The Console Results

```
Started POST "/user_activities" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 02:11:27 +0100
Processing by UserActivitiesController#create as HTML
    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Z6DP3METaYH2oczN11Mpewy4K4E1Gj+24twDM4NHI0y2abKn1CnW1M9993+u+3+9Gh4Rmz/k9g+/pVIpCltSNQ==", "user_activity"=>{"activity_id"=>"2", "user_activity_date"=>"2018-12-18", "user_activity_start"=>"09:56", "user_activity_end"=>"11:00", "user_activity_note"=>"still testing for errors in the app"}, "commit"=>"Create User activity"}
   The activity ID which is received is -> 2
   Date -> 2018-12-18
   Start Time -> 09:56
   End Time -> 11:00
   Activity Note -> still testing for errors in the app
       User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
       ↳ app/controllers/user_activities_controller.rb:54
       (0.4ms)  BEGIN
       ↳ app/controllers/user_activities_controller.rb:57
       UserActivity Create (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO `user_activities` (`user_activity_date`, `user_activity_start`, `user_activity_end`, `user_activity_note`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `user_id`, `activity_id`) VALUES ('2018-12-18 00:00:00', '09:56:00', '11:00:00', 'still testing for errors in the app', '2019-01-18 01:11:28', '2019-01-18 01:11:28', 1, 2)
       ↳ app/controllers/user_activities_controller.rb:57
       (0.4ms)  COMMIT
       ↳ app/controllers/user_activities_controller.rb:57
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/user_activities/7
Completed 302 Found in 111ms (ActiveRecord: 4.3ms)
```

I was having the ***accepts_nested_attribute_for*** on the **UserActivity** model and the variables used were exactly the same as that of its already set attributes and so they were conflicting.

**Right after I disable that, then I was able to save into the database and now everything is working good.**

I thank you for your support as they gave me an idea of where to channel my error-finding technique.

Comment: OK, but your answer would not work if you had not changed your `user_activity_params` per my answer. I spent significant time helping you here, and you've just answered your own question and marked it as correct. That's not how SO is supposed to work.

Comment: @moveson Please don't get offended because I have duly acknowledged your efforts by saying **I combined your various contributions and together I have been able to solve it**. I don't know how I could have taken your own alone as the answer then. Thanks for understanding

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your strong_parameters method. The API is not the most intuitive. The `#require` method returns just the value of the key that is required. So when you go to `#permit` certain attributes, you can't tell it to look for the `:user_activity` key again.

You might try playing around from the rails console to see what happens. First let's simulate a set of parameters:

```
>> params = ActionController::Parameters.new("user_activity"=>{"user_activity_note"=>"a test message I place here"})
#> <ActionController::Parameters {"user_activity"=>{"user_activity_note"=>"a test message I place here"}} permitted: false>
```

`require` returns an ActionController::Parameters object with just the value of the required key:

```
>> params.require(:user_activity)
#> <ActionController::Parameters {"user_activity_note"=>"a test message I place here"} permitted: false>
```

If we repeat the `:user_activity` key in our `permit` action, we get an empty params object back because everything that was in it is determined to be unpermitted. This does not happen silently; if you check your logs you will see that all your attributes were unpermitted.

```
>> params.require(:user_activity).permit(:user_activity => [:user_activity_note])
Unpermitted parameters: :user_activity_note
#> <ActionController::Parameters {} permitted: true>
```

But if we just list the attributes we need, we get the intended result:

```
>> params.require(:user_activity).permit(:user_activity_note)
#> <ActionController::Parameters {"user_activity_note"=>"a test message I place here"} permitted: true>
```

Change your `user_activity_params` method to:

```
def user_activity_params
  params.require(:user_activity).permit(:activity_id, :user_activity_date, :user_activity_start, :user_activity_end, :user_activity_note)
end
```

and it should work for you.

Comment: I cannot still receive the parameters from the **user_activity_params** because the error I am receiving says the parameter values are empty. **Field 'user_activity_date' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `user_activities` (`created_at`, `updated_at`, `user_id`)**

Comment: @BismarkAttaFrimpong Please show the server logs from your POST request.

Comment: Kindly look through the question. I have posted the log and also look at the answer I have provided for more info